# $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu $ in weak* , $\| \mu_n \| \rightarrow \|\mu\|$. Show that $ \int f d\mu_n \rightarrow \int f d\mu $ for $f\in BC(X)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M(X)$ be set of regular complex borel measures on LCH $X$. We know that $ M(X) = C_0 (X) ^*$ where $C_0(X)$ is the set of conitnuous  function vanishing at infinity.

Suppose $\mu_n$ is a sequence in $M(X)$ and converges to $ \mu \in M(X)$ in weak* topology and that $\| \mu_n \| \rightarrow \|\mu\|$.

I want to show that $ \int f d\mu_n \rightarrow \int f d\mu $ for every bounded continuous $f$.

I saw a hint that says there exists a compactly supported continuous function $g$ s.t. $\int g d\mu >\|\mu\| - \epsilon$ and $ |g| \leq 1$for small $\epsilon$. But I dont know how $g$ can be taken to be compactly supported and boundes by 1. I only know that by Riesz theorem that $g$ can be chosen as conitnuous and vanishing at infinity.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the definition of $\mu_n \to \mu$ in weak$^*$ topology?

Comment: I think OP is thinking of the space of complex measures as the dual of $C_c(X)$ so weak convergence means $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$ for all $f \in C_c(X)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited the question.

Comment: @mathworker21 integration w.r.t. a co tinuous function vanishing at infinity converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There exists a compact set $K$ such that $|\mu|(K^{c}) <\epsilon$. There exist an open set $U$ such that $K \subset U$ and $\overline {U}$ is compact. By Urysohn's Lemma there exist a continuous function $g$ with values in $[0,1]$ such that $g(x)=1$ for all $x \in K$ and $g(x)=0$ for all $x \in U^{c}$. This $g$ has compact support (contained in $\overline {U}$).

Comment: huh? the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is a regular complex borel measure such that $|\mu|(K^c) = \infty$ for each compact $K$

Comment: Lebesgue measure is not  a complex measure. Complex measures do not take infinite values.

Comment: How can I show the existence of such compact $K$? I see it holds if X is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Regularity of $\mu$ implies regularity of its total variation $|\mu|$. By definition this gives $|\mu|(X) =\sup \{|\mu| (K): K  \text  {compact} , K \subset X \}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have never seen such definition with compact sets. Can you offer me some reference for that specific definition? Does it hold bc X is locally compact?

Comment: Have seen the proof of Riesz Representation Theorem in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis? Everything I have used is clearly stated in that book.